# hasOwnProperty and object's properties access

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have very simple question.Is there any performance relation about accessing object's properties like `object[property]` and the number of properties ?? Is there some internal loop or something , same question about `hasOwnProperty` - any loops or just direct access like `array[index]` ??

Comment: can you please explain your question with an example ?

Comment: I have a object used for caching witch contains properties witch are objects themselves  and I'm wondering should I remove those properties when I don't need them.Would be there any performance difference if I have different amount of properties when accessing them.Memory is not a concern , though.

Comment: If you want to ask about performance, you should use that term in your question :-P

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a dynamic programming language: properties can be added to, and deleted from, objects on the fly. This means an object's properties are likely to change. Most JavaScript engines use a dictionary-like data structure as storage for object properties - each property access requires a dynamic lookup to resolve the property's location in memory. This approach makes accessing properties in JavaScript typically much slower than accessing instance variables in programming languages like Java and Smalltalk. In these languages, instance variables are located at fixed offsets determined by the compiler due to the fixed object layout defined by the object's class. Access is simply a matter of a memory load or store, often requiring only a single instruction.

use V8 (JavaScript engine) for better performance.